# Wordpress: trying to make a single static blank page that shows the header/sidebar/footer of my twenty fourteen template

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have made a static blank page that also shows my website's header/sidebar/footer in it. Now what i am trying to do is **get rid of the `'style'`** that my wordpress template css is forcing me to have on the page i am trying to create.

**`Here is my code:`**

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: My own page!
* Description: I made a page!
*/
require (dirname(dirname( __FILE__ )).'/wp-load.php');
get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">
    <?php
        if ( is_front_page() && twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() ) {
            // Include the featured content template.
            get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
        }
    ?>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">


            <!-- MY CONTENT!!! -->
            Hello2.
            <h1> hello.</h1>
            <p>hello</p>
            <input type="submit" name="connect" value="CONNECT" style="height:52px ; width:136px"/>
            <p>hi</p>
            <!--           -->


        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
    <?php get_sidebar( 'content' ); ?>
</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

*Any help appreciated.*

Comment: This should be on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to overwrite the styles which are already in the theme. For example, you can give an `id` to your submit button like `<input type="submit" name="connect" value="CONNECT" id="submitbutton">` and then style it according to your needs using CSS, for example:

```
input#submitbutton {
     height: 52px;
     width: 136px;
     background: blue;
     color: white;        
}
```

Same goes for the `<h1>` tags. Give an `<id>` to your `<h1>` tag like `<h1 id="hello"> hello.</h1>` and then style it according to your needs using CSS, for example:

```
h1#hello {
     color: black;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 20px;     
}
```

Use of Developer Tools over here will help you quite a lot in order to see how an element would look with your desired styles before actually making any changes to its CSS.

Comment: Although this is indeed a way to do things, if you need a lot of overrides, you may end up with conflicting CSS rules. However, if you only need to override a few things, it's a good way to do it...

Comment: @Shiro please mark my answer as the correct one if it has solved your issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to use something like

```
get_header('custom-header');
```

And use a custom header file to only load the stuff you want. You may need to create a custom function to override the scripts included by the theme...

Comment: see [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) for more info... You will also need to modify the function that includes the main css file... to load your custom css just for this page...